# What is the difference between source filtering, stored fields, and doc values in elsaticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've read the docs for [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-request-source-filtering.html), [stored fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/mapping-store.html), and [doc values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/doc-values.html).

> In certain situations it can make sense to store a field. For instance, if you have a document with a title, a date, and a very large content field, you may want to retrieve just the title and the date without having to extract those fields from a large _source field

---

> The stored_fields parameter is about fields that are explicitly marked as stored in the mapping, which is off by default and generally not recommended. Use source filtering instead to select subsets of the original source document to be returned.

---

> All fields which support doc values have them enabled by default.

### Example 1

I have documents with `title` (short string), and `content` (>1MB). I want to search for  matching titles, and return the title.

1. With source filtering

```
GET /_search
{ _source: "obj.title", ... }
```

2. With stored fields

```
GET /_search
{ _source: false, stored_fields: ["title"], ... }
```

3. With doc values

```
GET /_search
{_source: false, stored_fields: "_none_", docvalue_fields: "title", ... }
```

Okay, so

- Will the source filtered request read the full `_source`, title and content, from disk then apply the filter and return only the title, or will elasticsearch only read the  title from disk?
- Will the source filtered reques use doc values?
- Do stored fields store the analyzed tokens or the original value?
- Are stored fields or doc values more or less efficient than _source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will the source filtered request read the full _source, title and content, from disk then apply the filter and return only the title, or will elasticsearch only read the title from disk?

The document you send for indexing to Elasticsearch will be stored in a field called `_source` (by default). So this means that if your document contains a large amount of data (like in the `content` field in your case), the full content will be stored in the `_source` field. When using source filtering, first the whole source document must be retrieved from the `_source` field and then only the `title` field will be returned. You're wasting space because nothing really happens with the `content` field, since you're searching on `title` and returning only the `title` value.

In your case, you'd be better off to not store the `_source` document, and only store the `title` field (but it has some disadvantages, too, so [read this before you do](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html#disable-source-field)), basically like this:

```
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "store": true 
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Will the source filtered request use doc values?

doc-values are enabled by default on all fields, except on analyzed text fields. If you use `_source` filtering, it's not using doc values, as explained above, the `_source` field is retrieved and the fields you specified are filtered.

> Do stored fields store the analyzed tokens or the original value?

Stored fields store the exact value as present in the `_source` document

> Are stored fields or doc values more or less efficient than _source?

doc_values is a different beast, it's more of a optimization to store the tokens of non-analyzed fields in a way to will make it easy to sort, filter and aggregate on those values.

Stored fields (default is false) are also an optimization if you don't want to store the full source but only a few important fields (as explained above).
The `_source` field itself is a stored field that contains the whole document.

Comment: This [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-after) generally recommends against stored values.

Comment: I've updated the question with doc_value questions because I just found those in the docs.

Comment: You're mixing stored fields and doc values? Doc values are a completely different concept.

Comment: if a query includes `docvalue_fields: ["title"]` then title will be in the hits `fields`, just as if the query included `stored_fields: ["title"]`. Except doc_values is enabled by default for all types except analyzed types. They seem very similar to me

Comment: I understand that doc_values are optimized for sort/filter/aggregate, but are they poorly optimized for retrieval? Why does elasticsearch's query api include `docvalue_fields`?

Comment: Doc values are not poorly optimized for retrieval. ES wouldn't allow you to retrieve them otherwise. Also worth noting that doc value fields can work on fields that are not stored.

Comment: When, other then data types that cannot have doc_values, would you use stored fields instead of doc_values?

Comment: There's no right or wrong concerning the use of source filtering vs stored fields vs doc values. It always depends on the use case. Since your title field is of type text, doc values are out of the question anyway. As I mentioned in my answer, I would disable the source field and store the title field. That's it.